# I am finding trouble using log4js-protractor-appender

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node

My log4js.js file code

```
'use strict';
var log4js = require('log4js');
var log4jsGen = {
    getLogger: function getLogger() {
        log4js.loadAppender('file');
        log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.file('./ApplicationLogs.log'), 'logs');

        var logger = log4js.getLogger('logs');
        return logger;
    }
};

module.exports = log4jsGen;
```

My conf.js file(specific to appender section only)

```
"appenders": [{
    "type": "log4js-protractor-appender",
    "append": 'false',
    "maxLogSize": 20480,
    "backups": 3,
    "category": "relative-logger"
}],
```

Problem:

1) IS there a way that the logs will get overwritten in each run.
2) Why log4js-protractor-appender is not working, instead log4js is working, the merit of the previous is that it resolves the promises which is passed as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a great question. Yes  [log4js-protractor-appender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js-protractor-appender)  is awesome. It is built specially for Protractor based environments and it places all logger command in Protractor Control flow and resolves Protractor promises before logging.

You were using it incorrectly. The appender options are not part of Protractor config options but can be integrated. The approach you have is a little old one and I have updated by [blog post](http://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/04/how-to-implements-logs-for-protractorjavascript-based-test-automation-frameworks)

These are the steps as an answer to your question-2

Step 1: Install [log4js npm module](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node)

Step 2: Install [log4js-protractor-appender module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js-protractor-appender)

Step 3: Add the logger object creation logic in protractor `beforeLaunch()` and assign it onto ​​browser protractor global object

```
'use strict';
var log4js = require('log4js');
beforeLaunch:function(){
    if (fs.existsSync('./logs/ExecutionLog.log')) {
        fs.unlink('./logs/ExecutionLog.log')
    }
    log4js.configure({
        appenders: [
            { type: 'log4js-protractor-appender', category: 'protractorLog4js' },
            {
                type: "file",
                filename: './logs/ExecutionLog.log',
                category: 'protractorLog4js'
            }
        ]
    });
},
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.logger = log4js.getLogger('protractorLog4js');
},
```

Step 4: Use logger object in your tests by accessing through browser.logger

```
describe('sample test', function(){
    it('Sample Check', function(){
        browser.get("http://www.protractortest.org/#/");
        browser.logger.info("Testing Log4js");
        browser.sleep(5000);
        browser.logger.info('Displayed text is:', browser.getCurrentUrl());
        var elm = element(by.css('.lead'))
        browser.logger.info('Displayed text is:', elm.getText());
    });
});
```

But one thing to note is - This appender is just an console appender and will not be able to write to file. The file will still contain unresolved promises

Sample Output:

```
[21:54:23] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[21:54:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:54:25] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.1.5:60454/wd/hub
Started
[2017-02-03 21:54:30.905] [INFO] protractorLog4js - Testing Log4js
[2017-02-03 21:54:35.991] [INFO] protractorLog4js - Displayed text is: http://www.protractortest.org/#/
[2017-02-03 21:54:36.143] [INFO] protractorLog4js - Displayed text is: Protractor is an end-to-end test framework for Angular and AngularJS applications. Protractor runs tests against your application running in a real browser, interacting with it as a user would.
.
```

Answer to your Question 1: How to overwrite logs each run. I added a simple logic in `beforeLaunch()` to delete old logs if they exist and its part of the code snippet I pasted above

Comment: Failed: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined... this error I am getting... Its not reading the info which is called by browser.logger object

Comment: @hello_abhishek .. did you wrap the logger object onto browser.logger in `onPrepare()` as the code snippet in the answer shows

Comment: Thats weird .. @hello_abhishek .. can you run the exact config that I posted in the answer and see if its working to root out if any Env issue. Then we can debug your code for any incorrect usage

Comment: @AdityaReddy: can you help with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197816/getting-error-in-setting-up-log4js-protractor-appender-in-protractor

Answer (score 0):

I have check this issue with and followed the steps mentioned in Answer 1 and it works for me.

Earlier I was getting log output  in Console only but now I am getting log in console and file also.

I corrected the file path passing and Set type: "file" in log4js configure in conf file.

[Log4js in Conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp80d.png)

[Log appender in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcMXx.png)

Please let me know if you face any issue again.

Thanks

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you