# Unable to configure Log4js in Protractor

Tags: protractor

Can anyone please suggest how to configure log4js in protractor. Unable to proper documentation with clear steps to configure. I want a log file to be created with the all the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use log4js-protractor-appender. log4js-protractor-appender overrides log4js' default console appender. Just install it as a dependency

```
$ npm install log4js-protractor-appender --save
```

Then you can load it as any file appender. For example:

```
{
"appenders": [
    {
      "type": "log4js-protractor-appender-file"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can print log statements like below

```
logger.info('Navigating to /');
browser.get('/');
element(by.css('#someText')).getText().then(function (text) {
  logger.info('Displayed text is: ', text);
});
logger.info('Should be displayed last');
```

You can refer the following thread as well
[log4j-protractor-appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020911/i-am-finding-trouble-using-log4js-protractor-appender)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! i was looking some thing where a log file is generated and all the logs are available in that.